# Single responsibility principle React refactor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Knowing about the single responsibility principle I need to separate my logic from rendering. This code takes the inputs and calculate the rate for how much house mortgage rate you can afford. I'm trying to wrap my head around how to refactor the following code in the best way and make my code easy to read and re-use. Any ideas?

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';


class MonthlyPay extends Component {
  state = {
    cost: 0,
    houseCost: 0,
    downPayment: 0,
    termOfLoan: 0,
    annualInterestRate: 0
  }
   handleHouseCostChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            houseCost: e.target.value,
        });
   }

   handleDownPayment = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            downPayment: e.target.value,
        });
   }

   handleannualInterestRate = (e) => {
        this.setState({
           annualInterestRate : e.target.value,
        });
   }

   handleTermOfLoan = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            termOfLoan: e.target.value,
        });
   }
   handleCostChange = () => {
        const { houseCost, downPayment, termOfLoan, annualInterestRate } = this.state;
        const principal = houseCost - downPayment
        const lengthOfLoan = 12 * termOfLoan;
        const percentageRate = annualInterestRate / 1200
        console.log(lengthOfLoan);
        // Formula M = P[i(1+i)^n]/[(1+i)^n -1]
        const cost = (principal * percentageRate) / (1 - (Math.pow((1 + percentageRate) , lengthOfLoan * -1))).toString();
        this.setState({
            cost: cost.toFixed(2)
        })
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="counter">
          <div>
            <span className="counter-score">House Cost</span>
            <input type="number" placeholder="House Cost" onChange={(e) => this.handleHouseCostChange(e)}></input>
         </div>  
         <div>
            <span className="counter-score">Down Payment</span>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Down Payment" onChange={(e) => this.handleDownPayment(e)}></input>
        </div> 
        <div>
            <span className="counter-score">Mortgage Period (years)</span>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mortgage Period" onChange={(e) => this.handleTermOfLoan(e)}></input>
        </div>
         <div>
            <span className="counter-score">Interest Rate</span> 
            <input type="number" placeholder="Interest Rate" onChange={(e) => this.handleannualInterestRate(e)}></input>
        </div> 
                <button className="counter-action" onClick={this.handleCostChange}>Calculate</button>
                <span className="counter-score">{ this.state.cost }</span>
            </div>
            );
  }
}

export default MonthlyPay;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please do not flag this answer as useless right after you read the first sentence :) There might be something you can use.

Let's take a look at React documentation. There is a small part which describes the philosophy of the framework:

> React embraces the fact that rendering logic is inherently coupled
>   with other UI logic: how events are handled, how the state changes
>   over time, and how the data is prepared for display.
>
> Instead of artificially separating technologies by putting markup and
>   logic in separate files, React separates concerns with loosely coupled
>   units called “components” **that contain both**.

They recommend [this resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7cQ3mrcKaY) to make you feel more comfortable with these design decisions.

Another point is if you have logic for fetching data (communicating with backend let's say) together with UI logic. And for this React has some recommendations.

There is something called `presentational components` and `container components`.

Basically,

> Presentational components - How things look (markup, styles)

and

> Container components - How things work (data fetching, state updates)

I would recommend taking a look at [Dan Abramov's original article describing the concept of presentational and container components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) , he is kinda React Jedi :)

And here you can find code examples of both https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact , I really think it worth spend a few minutes here.

I don't think it's a good idea just to take your code and refactor it, I believe these resources will be much more valuable for you if you want to create better React Apps.

Happy hacking :)

Answer (score 1):

Two things I would do.
First move handleCostChange to a different non-react file.
I usually have a folder called utils where I keep complicated equations.
You could then import it like:

`import {calculateCostChange} from '../utils/CostCalculations.js'`

or something like that.

Second is you probably dont need all these simple state writing functions. Instead, you can have a single function that takes a key and value and saves state that way:

```
handleStateChange = (key, value) => {
  let mystate =  this.state;
  mystate[key] = value
  this.setState(mystate);
}
```

This will update or create a key value pair in your state that you can call like:

`onChange={(e) => this.handleStateChange('houseCost',e)`

Comment: Thank you! The second handleStateChange suggestion isn't working - the function returns nan. when I inspect the input element it's value changes to SyntheticEvent

Comment: Yes, inputs onChange gives the event. You have to get the value from the event target. Heres an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/o439qlolyq